# bookdown how to switch to fuse search engine and set options

Tags: r, search, bookdown, fuse

### How to switch Search Engine

Since bookdown version 0.23 it should be possible to switch from lunr.js to fuse.js, see ([bookdown news 0.23](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/main/NEWS.md#changes-in-bookdown-version-023)). This also provides an opportunity to configure some options of the search engine see [fuse.js options](https://fusejs.io/api/options.html).

I am looking for an option to search for two words on a page in any order. Hope to be able that only pages are shown which contain all words which are entered in the search box independent of the order. In case this is not possible I might need to add a DT or even a shiny app

I added the following code to the YAML in my index.Rmd

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "John Doe"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
      search:
        engine: fuse #lunr # or fuse https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/lunr-module
        # options to control/tune search engine behavior (for
        # fuse.js, refer to https://fusejs.io/api/options.html)
        options: 
          isCaseSensitive: true
          threshold: 0.0
          distance: 0        
----
```

### Check Search engine

The search behaviour still seems to be 'lunr' and the options set are not taken into account.

The file "_book\libs\gitbook-2.6.7\js\plugin-search.js" seems to indicate which search engine is being used and with which options, see [fuse,js options](https://fusejs.io/api/options.html)

in my case i see the following which indicates that my YAML was not taken into account:

```
gitbook.require(["gitbook", "lodash", "jQuery"], function(gitbook, _, $) {
    var index = null;
    var fuse = null;
    var _search = {engine: 'lunr', opts: {}};
```

What am I missing?

#### bs4_book

I also created a site with bs4_book. The file bs4_book.js clearly uses fuse and no references to lunr at all.

Comment: `var _search = {engine: 'lunr', opts: {}};` is not the right place to look at. This is: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/01fae11d4d8d6b2df63bf007f9bdb07f763be976/inst/resources/gitbook/js/plugin-search.js#L13 and your options are applied here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/01fae11d4d8d6b2df63bf007f9bdb07f763be976/inst/resources/gitbook/js/plugin-search.js#L47-L61 I just tested it, and the options have been correctly applied (the search is case-sensitive), so could you elaborate on "The search behaviour still seems to be 'lunr' and the options set are not taken into account"?

Comment: Apologies, was mistaken it does work indeed! many thanks Yihui. 
The search is indeed Case Sensitive I was looking at the highlighting.  I searched for EX and saw that Ex was highlighted in 'A Minimal Book Example' however didn't notice that there were no search results. When searching on Ex the search results display (as it should):
1 Prerequisites
5 Applications

Superb, many thanks. Bookdown is awesome
(now I need to see if I can tweak the search such that it only displays pages with all words on a page irrespective of the order)

Comment: No worries, and no need to apologize at all! I'm glad that it actually works. I can see that the highlighting is indeed confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality does work as described. You may also use the file ***_output.yml*** and include the following code:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    search:
      engine: fuse #lunr # or fuse https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/lunr-module
      # options to control/tune search engine behavior (for
      # fuse.js, refer to https://fusejs.io/api/options.html)
      options: 
        isCaseSensitive: true
        threshold: 0.0
        distance: 0
```